Lemma 2.3.3 in Sogge's Fourier Integrals in Classical Analysis
In the Section 2.3 of the book Fourier Integrals in Classical Analysis, Sogge may wanted to consider about the “Homogeneous 1” Riesz means —

Then he considered about the Fourier transform of the kernel $(1-q(-))_+^\delta$, where $\delta>0$. In the Lemma 2.3.3, he clamed
$$
A=\int e^{ix\xi} \,\chi(q(\xi)) \,\bigl[1-(1-q(\xi))_+^\delta\bigr]\,d\xi \lesssim 1+|x|^{-(n+1)}.
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{B_{1/4}}\leq\chi\leq\mathbf{1}_{B_{1/2}}$ is a $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ bump function.

It shouldn't seem that hard, but I can only prove $|A|\lesssim_\varepsilon 1 + |x|^{-(n+1)}\log x$:

Since $|\partial^\alpha\bigl[\,(1-\chi(|x|^\theta\cdot))\,\chi\,(1-(1-q)_+^\delta)\,\bigr] |\lesssim |\xi|^{1-|\alpha|}$ for any $\theta$, then
$$
A=\int e^{ix\xi} \chi(q(|x|^\theta\xi))\,\chi(q(\xi)) \,\bigl[1-(1-q(\xi))_+^\delta\bigr]\,d\xi  +
\int e^{ix\xi} \,\chi(q(\xi)) \,\bigl[1-(1-q(\xi))_+^\delta\bigr]\bigl[1- \chi(q(|x|^\theta\xi))\bigr]\,d\xi.
$$
The first is $O(|x|^{-(n+1)\theta})$, the last is (If $\alpha$ times integration by parts are used) $\lesssim |x|^{-\alpha}\int_{1\gtrsim|\xi|\gtrsim|x|^{-\theta}}|\xi|^{1-|\alpha|}d\xi\lesssim |x|^{-\alpha} + \frac{|x|^{-\theta(n-\alpha+1)-\alpha}}{|n-\alpha+1|}$, minimize the two terms we have
$$
|A| \lesssim 1+ |x|^{-(n+1)}\log x
$$

It's STRANGE! If a $\log(-)$ appears, this means that this approach is most likely not optimal.
